# Optimal way to convert a Managed C++ struct to native C++ which contain array of structs viceversa

Tags: c++, managed-c++

In Native C++, the structure looks like below.

```
typedef struct _DB_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_N
{
    OUT  ULONG               ulNumber;
    OUT  BOOLEAN             bActive;
    OUT  BOOLEAN             bPermanent;
} DB_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_N, *PDB_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_N;


typedef struct _Final_EmployeeDB_N  {
    OUT ULONG                      ulcount;
    OUT DB_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_N   stEmployeeArgs[30];
} Final_EmployeeDB_N, *PFinal_EmployeeDB_N;
```

In Managed C++, the structure looks like below.

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind::Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public value struct EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_CLR
{
public:
    UInt32                  ulNumber;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType::I1)]
    bool                    bActive;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType::I1)]
    bool                    bPermanent;
};

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind::Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public ref class EmployeeDB_CLR  {
public:
    UInt32                                  ulcount;
    array<EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_CLR>   ^stEmployeeArgs = gcnew array<EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_CLR>(30);
};
```

I need help in two aspects.
1) How to declare the fixed size array in Managed C++? I got some info from the [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/branbray/archive/2005/07/20/441099.aspx) to declare as inline_array. But is there any other way to perform this operation?

2) I want to convert the structures from managed C++ to native C++ and viceversa.

The below code converts the managed code to unmanaged.
I could achieve this in two ways:
1) by pointer convertion:

```
EmployeeDB_CLR ^hclrDetails; //assume data is present here

IntPtr UnmanagedMemAddr = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(Marshal::SizeOf(hclrDetails->stEmployeeArgs[0]));

    Final_EmployeeDB_N stDetails = { 0 };
    PFinal_EmployeeDB_N pDetails = &stDetails;

    stDetails.ulcount = hclrDetails->ulcount;
    for (int i = 0; i < hEnumDeviceArgs->stEmployeeArgs->Length; i++)
    {
        // Copy the managed struct to unmanaged memory.
        Marshal::StructureToPtr(hclrDetails->stEmployeeArgs[i],
            UnmanagedMemAddr,
            false);

        stDetails.stEmployeeArgs[i] = *static_cast<PDB_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_N>(UnmanagedMemAddr.ToPointer());
    }
```

2) I tried by using pin_Ptr<> and memcpy and it worked.

```
EmployeeDB_CLR ^hclrDetails; //assume data is present here
            Final_EmployeeDB_N stDetails = { 0 };

    pin_ptr<EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_CLR> tempPtr = &(hclrDetails->stEmployeeArgs[0]);
    memcpy(stDetails.stEmployeeArgs, tempPtr, hclrDetails->stEmployeeArgs->Length);
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.